# Django CSRF protection in Facebook Tab or Canvas App

Tags: django, facebook, canvas, csrf, facebook-canvas

Django's CSRF protection sets a cookie with the token on response and compares that to the token that is POSTed by the form. It appears in my Facebook Tab app that the csrf cookie is never being set in Safari. I know this has to with Safari's third party cookie policy.

So how are others who are writing Facebook Tab apps or Canvas apps able to set cookies on their app if the user has never visited their domain (which Safari will then allow the setting of the cookie)?

Comment: A dirty fix I once used was, If no csrf cookie set when the user launches the app, I redirected them to my domain, set the cookie there and redirected them back to the application. Definitely not the best solution, but I couldn't find another one.